# How to do First Pass Yield analysis using Elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

I'm starting to explore using Elasticsearch to help analyze engineering data produced in a manufacturing facility. One of the key metrics we analyze if the First Pass Yield (FPY) of any given process. So imagine I had some test data like the following:

```
 Item | Process | Pass/Fail | Timestamp
+-----+---------+-----------+----------
| A   | 1       | Fail      | 1       | <-- First pass failure
| A   | 1       | Pass      | 2       |
| A   | 2       | Pass      | 3       |
| A   | 3       | Fail      | 4       | <-- First pass failure
| A   | 3       | Fail      | 5       |
| A   | 3       | Pass      | 6       |
| A   | 4       | Pass      | 7       |
---------------------------------------
```

What I'd like to get out of this is the ability to query this index/type and determine what the first pass yield is by process. So conceptually I want to count the following in some time period using a set of filters:

1. How many unique items went through a given process step
2. How many of those items passed on their *first* attempt at a process

With a traditional RDBMS I can do this easily with subqueries to pull out and combine these counts. I'm very new to ES, so I'm not sure how to query the process data to count how many failures occurred for the first time an item went through that process

*My real end goal is to include this on a Kibana dashboard so my customers can quickly analyze the FPY data for different processes over various time periods. I'm not there yet, but I think Kibana will let me use a JSON query if this query requires that today.*

Is this possible with Elasticsearch, or am I trying to use the wrong tool for the job here?

Comment: As I think about this, would it be a better approach to add an additional field to these records with some sort of flag to indicate whether it was a "first pass" or not? Then I could use SQL to easily identify them when loading the data, and it would make the ES analysis much, much simpler.

Comment: I think you are right that you would need to add an identifier to your data in ES to note that it is a first pass.  If this is easily generated at load time it will certainly simplify your aggregations later.

Comment: Yeah, this is the approach I took after thinking about this some more. It was trivial to include a RANK() statement (I'm using SQL Server) to augment each test record with which pass it was (1, 2, 3, etc). Then it's easy to filter the data by first (or even last) pass.